# Images "pushing" others away

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically I want to list my images on my Bootstrap page, giving column spans per image.

Right now it looks the following:

[image]

However if one of the images is slightly larger than the others it'll push them off ruining the view as shown below (the first image with Harry Potter is the one being too big):

[image]

How can I make it so bootstrap always will display each image with the same size regardless of the images original size and not shove others away as above?

Here's the HTML displaying the images:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="/movies/watch/Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2_2011"><img src="/Images/Movies/Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2_2011.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="/movies/watch/Transformers: Dark of the Moon_2011"><img src="/Images/Movies/Transformers Dark of the Moon_2011.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="/movies/watch/The Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn - Part 1_2011"><img src="/Images/Movies/The Twilight Saga Breaking Dawn - Part 1_2011.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="/movies/watch/The Hangover Part II_2011"><img src="/Images/Movies/The Hangover Part II_2011.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="/movies/watch/Pirates of the Caribbean: On Stranger Tides_2011"><img src="/Images/Movies/Pirates of the Caribbean On Stranger Tides_2011.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="/movies/watch/Fast Five_2011"><img src="/Images/Movies/Fast Five_2011.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="/movies/watch/Mission: Impossible - Ghost Protocol_2011"><img src="/Images/Movies/Mission Impossible - Ghost Protocol_2011.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="/movies/watch/Cars 2_2011"><img src="/Images/Movies/Cars 2_2011.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="/movies/watch/Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows_2011"><img src="/Images/Movies/Sherlock Holmes A Game of Shadows_2011.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="/movies/watch/Thor_2011"><img src="/Images/Movies/Thor_2011.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="/movies/watch/Rise of the Planet of the Apes_2011"><img src="/Images/Movies/Rise of the Planet of the Apes_2011.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="/movies/watch/Captain America: The First Avenger_2011"><img src="/Images/Movies/Captain America The First Avenger_2011.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` on your `img` elements instead.

Using `inline-block`, all the images which are in a *line* will be treated as words in a line, and won't suffer the same fate as floats.

Comment: Yep, that works too, if you don't care if they are different heights.

Comment: I just added it but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I think it's being overridden by the 'float: left'. Also put a `float: none` on it.

Comment: I just added that but it still doesn't change anything.

Comment: See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RedDevil/HzMQp/

Perhaps the properties are being overridden. Open your inspector in Chrome and check the css properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class for the images and set the height explicitly, e.g.

```
.thumbnail img {
       height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I see - however I would like to have them keep their aspect ratio in regards to the width they get and not some fixed size.
But if there are no other solutions then I guess this will do.

Comment: If you just set the height they will keep their aspect ratio. If you set width then they will be a little squashed. Another option is to set `height: 100px; overflow: hidden;" on the a.thumbnail, but that will cut the image off.